# Programmatically determine whether the code is executing from the UI thread or not

Tags: android

In my Android app, I am extracting the code to update UI elements into a separate utility package for reuse. I would like my code to be proactive and update the UI differently if the current execution context is from a UI thread versus a non-UI thread.

Is it possible to programmatically determine whether the current execution is happening on the UI thread or not?

A trivial example of what I am looking to achieve is this - my app updates a lot of `TextView`s all the time. So, I would like to have a static utility like this:

```
public static void setTextOnTextView(TextView tv, CharSequence text){
    tv.setText(text);
}
```

This obviously won't work if called from a non-UI thread. In that case I would like to force the client code to pass in a `Handler` as well, and post the UI operation to the handler.

Comment: `if (Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread())` will be `true` if you're on the UI-thread. But, **srsly**, just call `Activity#runOnUiThread(Runnable)` or `View#post(Runnable)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use the runOnUiThread method in `Activity`

It takes a runnable and either runs it straight away (if called from the UI thread), or will post it to the event queue of the UI thread.

That way you don't have to worry about if your method has been called from the UI thread or not.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Don't know how I missed it!

Answer (score 1):

When you're **not sure** the code is executed on the UI thread, you should do:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

This way, whether you're on the UI thread or not, it *will be* executed there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `View` [post](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method.

Your code would be:

```
tv.post(new Runnable() {

  public void run() {
     tv.setText(text);
  }

});
```

Comment: The document says "This method can be invoked from outside of the UI thread only when this View is attached to a window". What does this mean? What I showed in my question was a trivial example - I might be doing other things like hiding or showing a `View`, showing or dismissing a dialog, and lots more. Finally, isn't there a performance penalty in posting a `Runnable` even if I am already on the UI thread?

Comment: Regarding your last question: No __severe__ penalty, you'll still be creating an unnecessary object (the `Runnable`), but `Activity#runOnUiThread(Runnable)` for instance, will execute your `Runnable` directly and not post it to some queue and delay it. `View#post(Runnable)` **will** however post your request to a handler and possibly delay it somewhat if called from the UI thread.